# SKSpriteNode resize and update SKPhysicsJointPin anchor point

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to learn `SpriteKit`. I have a balloon (`SKSpriteNode`) that after running a `SKAction` for resizing, the balloon will change its size. the balloon has a string attached to it. the string is just multiple `SKSpriteNode` attached with `SKPhysicsJointPin` with each other. I've inverted gravity so the balloon with attached string got upward and after 3sec timeout it gets smaller. so far it works except for the start attached point of the string is not moved to the correct position of balloon. how to solve this issue?

[image]

so i'm adding only the necessary part here otherwise the post gets too bulky. so again see balloon has skaction which resizes the balloon, and how to move the string to correct position while resizing?

Balloon is subclassed `SKSpriteNode`

```
 Balloon *balloon = [Balloon spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"balloon.png"];
 [balloon setPosition:CGPointMake(200, CGRectGetMinY(scene.frame))];
 [balloon setName:@"balloon"];
 [balloon setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
 [balloon setPhysicsBody:[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:55]];
 balloon.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
 [balloon.physicsBody setRestitution:0.4f];
 [balloon.physicsBody setFriction:0.0f];
 CGPoint attachPoint = CGPointMake(200, CGRectGetMinY(scene.frame));
 //create the rope
 SKRopeNode *rope = [SKRopeNode new];
 rope.name = @"ropeParent";
 [scene addChild:rope];
 [rope setAttachmentPoint:attachPoint toNode:balloon];   
 rope.ropeLength = 6;    
 [rope runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:4.5],    [SKAction removeFromParent]]]];   
 [balloon runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:4],   [SKAction scaleTo:balloon.yScale/2 duration:0.5], [SKAction removeFromParent]]]];
```

this how i create rope method for creating the length

```
    SKSpriteNode *firstPart = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"rope_part.png"];
    firstPart.position = _positionOnStartNode;
    firstPart.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:firstPart.size];
    firstPart.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;

    for (int i=1; i<ropeLength; i++) {
    SKSpriteNode *ropePart = [firstPart copy];
    ropePart.position = CGPointMake(firstPart.position.x, firstPart.position.y - (i*ropePart.size.height));
    ropePart.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:ropePart.size];
    ropePart.physicsBody.allowsRotation = YES;
    [self.scene addChild:ropePart];
     }
```

and this is for adding joints for the rope before

```
SKNode *nodeA = balloon;
SKSpriteNode *nodeB = [_ropeParts objectAtIndex:0];

SKPhysicsJointPin *joint = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA: nodeA.physicsBody
                                                       bodyB: nodeB.physicsBody
                                                      anchor: _positionOnStartNode];
    for (int i=1; i<_ropeParts.count; i++) {
    SKSpriteNode *nodeA = [_ropeParts objectAtIndex:i-1];
    SKSpriteNode *nodeB = [_ropeParts objectAtIndex:i];
    SKPhysicsJointPin *joint = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA: nodeA.physicsBody
                                                           bodyB: nodeB.physicsBody
                                                          anchor: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(nodeA.frame),
                                                                              CGRectGetMinY(nodeA.frame))];
    [self.scene.physicsWorld addJoint:joint];
    }
```

Comment: You should write some code that explain what have you tried..

Comment: that image above is produced by my example code! and  I have explained that above.

Comment: We cannot tell what is going wrong with your code if you do not show us your code.

Comment: @HashmatKhalil that's as maybe but if you've an error in your code, we're not going to see it, are we? You need to supply the code (the smallest, complete version that generates the error) so we can try it ourselves if necessary.

Comment: the balloon's physicsbody in nil when you try to attach the string.

Comment: so i have posted the necessary code parts if that helps you guys to pinpoint my error.